# Plot a function $\varphi=\arccos\frac{r-1}{r^2}$ in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Plot a function in polar coordinates: $$\varphi=\arccos\frac{r-1}{r^2}$$
Is there any way to express $r$ through $\varphi$? I don't really get how to do this ploblem without it. Restrictions: $$r \ge \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2} \\ 0\le \varphi\le \pi$$ I'm stuck and have no clue how to graph it

Comment: What is $\varphi $ ?

Comment: It's angle. So there is function $\varphi=\varphi(r)$ but I need to graph Inverse function

Comment: Oh so $\phi$ and $\varphi$ is same ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if I confused you with my bad latex

Comment: Can convert this to cartesian  and then plot ? Or it is must to plot in polar ?

Answer (score 0):

Start by 
$$
(cos \phi) r^2 - r +1 = 0
$$
solve the quadratic equation and apply the restrictions.

Comment: so $r=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4cos\varphi}}{2}$ or $r=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4cos\varphi}}{2}$